# How to set IsModified to false on a property in a related Collection in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.1

I am using Asp.Net Core 1.1 and I have two classes:

```
public class Scale
{
    [Key]
    public int ScaleId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public decimal DefaultValue { get; set; }

    public List<ScaleLabel> Labels { get; set; }
}

public class ScaleLabel
{
    [Key]
    public int ScaleLabelId { get; set; }

    public int ScaleId { get; set; }
    public virtual Scale Scale { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

When a scale is used, all its ScaleLabels should be prohibited to update except for their Label property.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ScaleId,Name,Description,DefaultValue,Labels")] Scale scale)
    {
        if (id != scale.ScaleId)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (IsScaleUsed(id))
                {
                    _context.Scales.Attach(scale);
                    _context.Entry(scale).Collection(c => c.Labels).IsModified = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    _context.Update(scale);
                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ScaleExists(scale.ScaleId))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(scale);
    }
```

If I use `_context.Entry(scale).Collection(c => c.Labels).IsModified = false;` then nothing is updated, and if I don't use it, then all ScaleLabels are updated. I want to specify which properties of the Scale's Labels navigation property are modified and which are not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than playing with `IsModified` property of the related `CollectionEntry`, you need to use the `IsModified` property of the `PropertyEntry` returned by `Property` method (or `Properties` property) of `EntityEntry` for each element of the related collection (basically the same way as you would do for specific property of any entity).

In other words, instead of

```
_context.Entry(scale).Collection(c => c.Labels).IsModified = false;
```

you would use something like this:

```
foreach (var label in scale.Labels)
    foreach (var p in _context.Entry(label).Properties.Where(p => p.Metadata.Name != "Label"))
        p.IsModified = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. I also needed to use update instead of attach and add condition for only modified entities so that new ones can be added.